# Changing id attribute in an input after clonning a table row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table and when clicking on "add button" a new table row is added. I was able to make it work by using some jquery such as:

```
$(function () {
$('.add-line-button').click(function () {
    var rowNum = ($("#table tbody tr").length);
    const rowId = 'tablerow[' + rowNum + ']';
    var collectionNamePrefix = 'tablerow[' + rowNum + ']';
    var newRow = $("#table tbody tr[id='tablerow[0]").clone().attr('id', rowId).attr('name', collectionNamePrefix);

    $("table[id='table'] tbody").append(newRow);
    document.querySelector("#table tbody tr[id='tablerow[" + rowNum + "]'] td#findTaskName input").setAttribute('id', 'hdnTaskName[' + rowNum + ']').setAttribute('value', "");
    document.querySelector("#table tbody tr[id='tablerow[" + rowNum + "]'] td#findactivitiesName input").setAttribute('id', 'hdnActivityName[' + rowNum + ']').setAttribute('value', "");
    
});
```

});

My rowNum variable is to determine the row index, then I use this parameter to change the id of the new table row, after cloning it.

I have two hidden inputs, so that I'm able to get the text of a select list. However, when i add a new row, I want to change the id of these inputs, so they are in accordance to the row they are in. Ex: if rowNum = 1, then the input id="hdnTaskName[1]".

When I do the first setAttribute for td#findTaskName the input works fine with the id that I want.
However for the td#ActivitiesName the same does not happen? It doesn't set its id and keeps the id of the first row

Comment: Could you show your table ?

Comment: Do not do this. Dynamic `id` attributes generated at runtime are an anti-pattern which cause more problems that they solve. A much better way to do what you're attempting it to use the same class on every cloned element within the row. Then use DOM traversal methods such as `find()`, `closest()` etc. to relate elements to each other within delegated event handlers.